# Pressing ^p compiles on texstudio

Tags: texstudio

everytime I try to type ^p on Textudio it starts compiling the file, which is really annoying. I would like to know if it's possible to disable this feature. I searched for an option on the options menu but I didn't find anything.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can find any defined keystrokes in "Options / configure TeXStudio / Shortcuts"
[image: shortcuts menu]
And from there most likely in the "Tools" section.